# How can I fix blocking issue on a new install of ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: jms, hornetq, activemq-artemis

I've been tasked with evaluating ActiveMQ Artemis for JMS clients.  I have RabbmitMQ experience, but none with ActiveMQ Artemis & JMS.

I installed Artemis to my local machine, created a new broker per the instructions, and set it up as a Windows service.  The Windows service starts and stops just fine.  I've made no changes to the `broker.xml` file.

For my first test I'm trying to perform a JMS queue produce/consume from a stand alone Java program.  I'm using the code from the Artemis User Manual in the Using JMS section, (without using JNDI):

```java
TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration = new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName());
ConnectionFactory cf = ActiveMQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithoutHA(JMSFactoryType.CF,transportConfiguration);

Queue orderQueue = ActiveMQJMSClient.createQueue("OrderQueue");
Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(orderQueue);
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(orderQueue);

connection.start();

TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is an order");
producer.send(message);

TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage)consumer.receive();
System.out.println("Got order: " + receivedMessage.getText());
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
WARN: AMQ212054: Destination address=jms.queue.OrderQueue is blocked. If the system is configured to block make sure you consume messages on this configuration.
```

My research hasn't been conclusive on if this is a server side setting, or having the producer send without blocking.  I haven't been able to find a producer send method that has a blocking boolean, only persistence.  Any ideas on where to focus?  Thanks.

Edit: new `address-setting` element added to `broker.xml` dedicated to this queue:

```xml
<address-setting match="jms.queue.OrderQueue">
    <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>
    <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
</address-setting>
```

Comment: Even though AMQ212054 warn message, did the consumer managed to read the TextMessage?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found this on further research in the user manual:

> max-disk-usage  The max percentage of data we should use from disks.
> The System will block while the disk is full. Default=100

and in the log after service startup with no messages published yet:

> WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222210: Storage usage is beyond max-disk-usage. System will start blocking producers.

so I think no matter my address settings, it would start to block.  Looking at the max-disk-usage setting in broker.xml, it was set to 90.  Documentation default says 100, I set to that, no startup log warnings, and my test pub/sub code now works.

Comment: It's worth noting that the default value for `max-disk-usage` referenced by the documentation is the _code_ default so that if you don't set `<max-disk-usage>` in `broker.xml` it will be `100`. However, the `broker.xml` output by the `create` command uses `90` for `<max-disk-usage>`.

Answer (score 0):

This warn message comes when address policy set to BLOCK and memory reached. Check [address policy](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.0.0/paging.html) set in broker.xml. If it is set to BLOCK, change it to PAGE. Or consume pending messages from OrderQueue.

Comment: Thanks for this, I checked this, and both address-setting entries are set to PAGE for address-full-policy.  I did some further searching and came across this page: https://communities.ca.com/thread/241725820   My broker.xml was missing the max-size-bytes and page-size-bytes entries, so I added those.  But now the Broker won't start up with those added, I get a windows service startup error.

Comment: It was a generic service won't start message.  However, I did some research at the link you provided.  I added an additional address-setting element dedicated to this queue (see original post for new element)    
The broker starts fine now, but I'm still getting the blocking message.

Answer (score 0):

By default max-disk-usage value is set as 90(%) and if the remaining free space size is less than 10%, then this warn message will be shown and no messages will be received until you adjust the parameter or free up space beyond 10%.